# How vmware copies data from guest to host?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualbox

Because of VMware tools I can copy a string from guest OS to host OS and vice a versa. I want to know how this functionality works ? what VMware performs so that clipboard is shared between two different OS.

Yesterday, I learnt about VARIANT struct in Microsoft COM. VARIANT is like a middle ware on which some engine will run and allow data of one type accessible in other format of some other language.[please correct me if this is wrong or I am not talking right]

So just want to ask, is something like this works in virtual machines ? Because this functionality is so so helpful that I want understand this concept.

I have not tried in virtual box yet but if it supports same functionality then how do they work ? I would like to read about it if any links found.

Answer (score 0):

Since your virtual machine still runs on the true hardware of your host machine it although uses its peripheral devices and hardware.

So vmware or virtual machines in general has to "root" this device to your virtual OS.

So what Vmware (especially VMWARE Tools) does is when you have copied something into your clipboard, to synchronize this data with the second clipboard. So it provides interfaces between your host data like clipboard or date an time and sets it in your virtual OS.

Have a look here:

- http://smallbusiness.chron.com/sharing-clipboard-vmware-35825.html
- http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/new_guest_tools_ws.html.

This does not exactly answers your question, but should give some ideas on further research.