# VMWare copy paste from host to local

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vdi

First of all thank you for helping me,

For work we need to use a VDI with Windows 10 through WMWare Horizon Client (host) from a Virtual Box instance with Windows 7 (guest), and the Local PC has windows 10  (local)

We would need to be able to copy and paste from the VDI (host) to the Local PC

We have read:

- [Vmware 12: Can't copy paste between Host and Virtual computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213996/vmware-12-cant-copy-paste-between-host-and-virtual-computer)
- [How vmware copies data from guest to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397401/how-vmware-copies-data-from-guest-to-host)
- https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Horizon-Desktops-and-Apps/horizon-view-clipboard-copy-and-paste-windows-client-to-vdi-both/m-p/461677/highlight/true
- https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Not-able-to-copy-paste-from-Host-machine-to-VM/m-p/502839#M26757

But nothing worked as expected,

Could you help us?

Thanks

**EIDT:**
We can copy from host VDI to Virtual Machine guest, but not from VDI to Local PC directly

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows host, choose Settings > Preferences. On the Input tab, clear the Enable copy and paste to and from virtual machine check box.

Comment: ...and for Mac users - we are out of luck.